# Running a script after tty1 has loaded

Tags: debian, shell-script

I have been attempting to write a script to run dcled on start up, the program that runs [this](http://www.dreamcheeky.com/led-message-board).  I am using Debian Jessie with multiarch enabled.  This is essentially a small file server.  I am attempting to do this because I thought it would be cool to see a little led screen print out every time someone attempts to log into the server without having to actually log in and read `/var/log/auth.log`.  Here is the script I have so far.

```
!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          dcled.sh
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: dcled
# Description:       print file to dcled
### END INIT INFO

# Author: 

PATH=/usr/bin

tail -f /var/log/auth.log | dcled -s 50 -p 4
```

The script works and runs the last line of `/var/log/auth.log` (when something is new is written to it), but the [`tty` terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Okxq.jpg) does not show up.  I have used by `update-rc.d` and `insserv` to attempt to do get this to work 100% correct to no avail.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `tail -f /var/log/auth.log | dcled -s 50 -p 4 &`.